# how to fix error message "Invalid attribute tag: 1." in dlmwrite function

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write integer data into CSV file in every iteration, this is my code and I've got this error message

**Error:**  using dlmwrite (line 112) Invalid attribute tag:1

**My code:**

```
    clc;
clear;
close all;

predictedNumber = 2;

for dataCounter = 1:3000
   for  dataPredictionCounter = 1:200

       dlmwrite('finalResults.csv',predictedNumber,'-append',dataCounter,dataPredictionCounter);

   end
end
```

dataCounter and dataPredictionCounter are row and column numbers.

Comment: Did you check the values of `dataCounter` and `dataPredictionCounter`? It could be they are not valid.

Comment: Yes, I checked values. they're valid as you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `dlmwrite` incorrectly. You have to remove `dataCounter` and `dataPredictionCounter` because those aren't arguments to dmlwrite. This will be very slow. You can put everything into an array first and then write the array to the file with `csvwrite`.

```
M = rand(50,2);
csvwrite('myFile.txt',M)
```